# C++ 64bit project with PDCurses static link library via Clion's CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, 64-bit, clion, pdcurses

Recently I have acquired the "curses.h" and built the PDCurses "pdcurses.a" library file thanks to: 
https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-pdcurses
package. I also have prepared cmake files:

```
# pdcurses-config.cmake
set(PDCURSES_LIBDIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")
set(PDCURSES_INCLUDE_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/include")
set(PDCURSES_LIBRARIES "-L${PDCURSES_LIBDIR} -lpdcurses -static -Wall -Werror")
string(STRIP "${PDCURSES_LIBRARIES}" PDCURSES_LIBRARIES)



# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MatrixAlgebra)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(PDCURSES_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(PDCURSES REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PDCURSES_INCLUDE_DIRS})


set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(MatrixAlgebra ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(MatrixAlgebra ${PDCURSES_LIBRARIES})
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to link a simple "Hello World!" console program because either I am getting this:

> mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpdcurses
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\MatrixAlgebra.dir\build.make:97: MatrixAlgebra.exe] Error 1
>   mingw32-make.exe[2]:**  [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/MatrixAlgebra.dir/all] Error 2
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]:  **[CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/MatrixAlgebra.dir/rule] Error 2
>   mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: MatrixAlgebra] Error 2

or this (when I change "pdcurses.a" to "libpdcurses.a"):

> Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

I simply don't know what to do to make it proceed without problems.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't treat target_link_libraries() like commandline to feed it with parameters like -Wall

I don't know pdcurses, but when find_package finds that lib you should probably use something like:

```
target_link_libraries(MatrixAlgebra pdcurses::pdcurses)
```

Comment: I was trying to achieve solution by mimicking the "sdl2-config.cmake". And to be exact a line of code like this one:

set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "-L${SDL2_LIBDIR}  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main ... -static-libgcc")